# Change text to a image

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to programming and have been learning. I would like someone to explain to me how I can exchange these texts for images as in the example
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/748951699950927913/1092194621859319870/image.png
to
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/748951699950927913/1092195435831120002/image.png

I was testing with this images:

```css
/* Grupos  */
.qeel_groupes a {
        color: #ffffff;
        display: block;
        font-weight: 700;
        margin: .8rem 0;
        padding: .5rem 0;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        transition: .5s all;
        border-radius: 5px;
}
 
.qeel_groupes a:hover {
       color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
 
a#q_basic {background: #000000;}
a#q_magic {background: #ad3737;}
a#q_wizard {background: #3e3b96;}
```

```html
<div class="qeel_bloc">
    <div class="qeel_dernier">
        {NEWEST_USER}
    </div> 
    <div class="qeel_groupes">
        <a href="g2-narradores" id="q_basic">
            Narradores
        </a>
        <a href="g3-pirata" id="q_magic">
            Piratas
        </a>
        <a href="g4-marinha" id="q_wizard">
            Marinheiros
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have try to replace the text to a  but it didn't work. I'm sorry, i'm really learning, if someone can explain me

Comment: Please upload the images within the question editor and print code as typed code.   Thank you.

Comment: You need to use `<img>` elements to instert images, or use CSS to change the `background-image` of another element.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `<img>` elements to insert images, or use CSS to change the `background-image` of another element.

In this example a `background-image` is applied to anchor elements.

```css
a#q_basic {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/sprites.svg);
  text-indent: -9999em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 188px;
  height: 50px;
}
a#q_magic {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/sprites.svg);
  text-indent: -9999em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 188px;
  height: 50px;
}
a#q_wizard {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/sprites.svg);
  text-indent: -9999em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 188px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="qeel_bloc">
    <div class="qeel_dernier">
        {NEWEST_USER}
    </div> 
    <div class="qeel_groupes">
        <a href="g2-narradores" id="q_basic">
            Narradores
        </a>
        <a href="g3-pirata" id="q_magic">
            Piratas
        </a>
        <a href="g4-marinha" id="q_wizard">
            Marinheiros
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```